# Moving data within pre-allocated memory

Tags: c++

I have been trying to implement a defragmenter for pre-allocated memory. Assume that we have void pointer with pre-allocated memory for `sizeof(int) * 3`:

```
void* ptr = operator new(sizeof(int) * 3);
```

And init first and third chunks of memory

```
int *one = new (ptr) int(1);
int *three = new (ptr + sizeof(int) * 2) int(3);
```

And here is my question: is it possible to shift value from `(ptr + sizeof(int) * 2)` (*three) to second `(ptr + sizeof(int))` position without knowing the value type?

`int *second = new (ptr + sizeof(int)) int(*three);` is not an option.

Comment: you need to at least know the value *size*, and then use `memcpy` or `memmove`

Comment: `int *three = new (ptr + sizeof(int) * 2) int(3);` does not compile. Cannot perform arithmetic on a `void` pointer.

Comment: GCC compiles it with warnings.

Comment: @SergeyFilipovich -- that's a GCC extension.

Comment: @SergeyFilipovich You're right. It does compile with warnings. For GCC I [tried with `-pedantic` and `-Werror`](https://godbolt.org/g/jgucjV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You must know the size of the type that has been erased by `void*`. If you cannot recover the type (`int`), or rather the number of bytes that type occupies (`sizeof(int)`) then you cannot reliably operate on the underlying memory.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @SergeyFilipovich: I recommend storing `sizeof(int)` into a `std::size_t` that you can use later. Also, be sure to cast your `void*` to `char*` to perform arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to know and preserve the size of stored type. More importantly, stored type must be [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType), at least [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable). Otherwise stored objects may be very much surprised finding themselves moving across the memory. If you need to support such non-trivial types, you must use their real copy or move constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: What kind of errors I will receive if I move non-trivial types with memmove? I know how to solve trouble with object pointers.

Comment: If you `memmove` an arbitrary C++ object, you can get all sorts of errors. Double destruction of moved-out object. No destruction (leak) of moved-into object. Breaking type invariants by changing object identity (address). Try to `memmove` a non-empty `std::vector` for example and see what happens using Valgrind or sanitizers.